# EE 2.6.0 not parsing {page_url}

Tags: structure, pages

Is anyone else find that {page_url}, whether using Pages or Structure, is not being parsed at all?

Answer (score 4):

I found that the new Parser logic doesn't account for page_url in their $this->_urls block. Adding the following after line 423 of Simple_variable.php is the fix:

```
elseif ($key == "page_url")
{
    $tagdata = str_replace(LD.$key.RD, $data['page_url'], $tagdata);
}
```

Comment: Lovely, I was looking through that logic and noticed it was missing some things too. There are other variables I found not parsing.